# Condition of a space for strong convergence

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $B$ a reflexive space (maybe $A$ must be reflexive also ?) . If we have a compact embedding $A\hookrightarrow B$, then if $(v_n)$ is a bounded sequence of $A$, then there is a subsequence that converge weakly in $A$.

Do we have a condition on $B$ to have the strong convergence of the subsequence ? (maybe separability ?)

Comment: Compactness alone (by definition!) is sufficient to conclude that a sequence bounded in $A$ has a convergent subsequence in $B$.

Comment: @gerw: The convergence is weak not strong. I'm asking a condition to have a strong convergent subsequence.

Comment: Why? A compact operator turns bounded sets into (strongly) precompact sets!

Comment: @gerw: take the embedding $W^{1,p}\subset L^p$, if $(v_n)$ is bounded, it has a subsequence that converge weakly but not strongly a priori.

Comment: @gerw: Call the compact operator $T$.  Given a bounded sequence $v_n \in A$, we know (if $A$ is separable and reflexive; important!) that there is a subsequence $v_{n_k}$ that converges weakly.  We also know that $T v_n$ has strongly convergent subsequences, but how do we know that $T v_{n_k}$ is one of them?

Comment: @user386627: Do you want to have the strong convergence in $A$ or in $B$?

Comment: @NateEldredge: But a compact operator sends weakly convergent sequences to strongly convergent sequences, doesn't it?